# Read embedded text from image with python when the texts were added with Qt

Tags: python, image, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

In Qt it is possible to add embedded text to an image as key-values pairs ([QImage::setText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setText)).
Is it possible to retrieve this information with python without using PyQt?

**EDIT** Solved!

Owing to Schollii and the second link in his answer the solution was easy: ***image.info***

```
>>> import PIL.Image, PIL.PngImagePlugin
>>> fname = "c:\\tmp\\i1.png"
>>> image = PIL.Image.open(fname)
>>> for k, v in image.info.iteritems(): print k, "=>", v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PNG image, what you have to search for is a library that supports reading "text chunks", in particular chunks of type tEXt, and possibly zEXt and iEXt. For example, PIL seems to have a plugin that supports PNG's text, zext but not iext chunks:

- https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py
- https://gist.github.com/dankrause/4354803

Not sure about other formats.